# error: too few arguments to function ‘ptr’ , need to eval_time from a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I have a small problem with my program.
I want to eval the time from a function and the compiler gives me an error.
I know were the problem is, but I just dont know how to fix it :/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int isPerfect(int zahl){
int zaehler1, zaehler2, summe;
for(zaehler1=1;zaehler1<=zahl;zaehler1++){
    summe=0;
    for(zaehler2=1;zaehler2<=zaehler1/2;zaehler2++){
        if(zaehler1%zaehler2==0){
        summe=summe+zaehler2;
        }
    }
}
return summe;
}

double eval_time(int(*ptr)(int)){
    time_t begin,end;
    begin=time(NULL);
    (*ptr)();  //compiler shows error here!
    end=time(NULL);
    return difftime(end,begin);
    }

int main(void){
    int zahl;
    for(zahl=1;zahl<=500;zahl++){
        if(isPerfect(zahl)==zahl){
        printf("%d ist eine perfekte Zahl!\n", zahl);
        }
    }
    printf("Die Zeit die gebraucht wurde: %.2lf s\n",eval_time(isPerfect));
return 0;
}
```

So my question is what do i need to change there so it evals the time from the funtion "isPerfect" ?
Sorry my variables are in german, I hope that's not a problem ;)

Comment: The function-pointer you have in `eval_time` takes an `int` argument. You need to provide that argument. Just like the error is saying. Exactly *what* you should pass is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You *have* to pass a parameter, perhaps like this:

```
double eval_time(int(*ptr)(int), int zahl){
    time_t begin,end;
    begin=time(NULL);
    (*ptr)(zahl);
    -------^
    end=time(NULL);
    return difftime(end,begin);
}
```

Another problem is that you might have to call the functions lots and lots of times between `begin` and `end` to actually get a measurable difference in the `time()` values.

Comment: Also `ptr(zahl)` would just do.

Comment: ok, I can compile now , but the output it always 0.00 sec even if the program takes over 1 min to get trough when I increase the value of zahl<=500 to zahl<=50000000

Comment: @slauko: What about running the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on?

Comment: I would like to try this out, but in still a newbie in programming and started 1 month ago and never used a debugger yet :o wasnt needed till now I gues:/

Comment: @slauko - You would have to add a loop inside `eval_time`, not int `main`.

Comment: @Slauko Paste the whole (new) code you got now as an update in your question post. This makes it possible for us to help you :). Happy coding!